# jQuery get outerWidth() of #foo

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, debugging

Hi really quick question, how do I get the `outerWidth()` of an element #foo with jQuery?

One catch is that this is nested within a function for `$("a.preview")` but I need to get the **width of the ID and NOT the class** `#preview`

```
    while ((left + 400) > window.innerWidth){
        left -= 400 + #preview.outerWidth();
        }
```

Comment: I don't understand. Could you include some more code and markup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since **jQuery 1.8** the only way to get outerWidth is to add the boolean parameter to the function call. outerWidth() no longer works as a getter of the outerwidth. Now, since jQuery 1.8, it returns the DOM object itself (s. http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/16/jquery-1-8-box-sizing-width-csswidth-and-outerwidth/).

Now you have to call:

```
$('#preview').outerWidth(addMargin)
```

with parameter addMargin

```
false (means without adding margin to the outerwidth)
```

or

```
true (with margin adding to outerwidth)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
jQuery("#preview").outerWidth()
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
while ((left + 400) > window.innerWidth){
     left -= 400 + $('#preview')[0].outerWidth;
}
```

Comment: @Brian, can you make a fiddle on jsfiddle.net and show me what is happening?

Comment: ahhh haaa @Brian both of the codes did the same thing, but to the victor goes the spoils ^_^